# STS request with certificate authentication in SoapUI

Tags: certificate, soapui, keystore, adfs, sts-securitytokenservice

I have to do RequestSecurityToken request with certificate signature and timestamp with SoapUI to get security token to use it in other requests, but I have problem to implement it correctly.

Here are correct request, with different application, but with same certificate:

```
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2016-10-24T14:35:54.851Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2016-10-24T14:40:54.851Z</u:Expires>
    </u:Timestamp>
    <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-e5fff67c-e3ce-4c63-86da-9661adfd6e0c-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">...MIIFgTCCBGmgAwIBAgIKOePZb(shortened)...</o:BinarySecurityToken>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="#_0">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>tsLKDNU0lJ5SB1p75WGVjd7LMHc=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference URI="#_1">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>4QwJS9rCbZb1B3DcR37qnuJgSl4=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>...gmAXzaf8hhj44/M0Q(shortened)...</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:Reference URI="#uuid-e5fff67c-e3ce-4c63-86da-9661adfd6e0c-2"/>
            </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</o:Security>
```

In SoapUI, in WSS config I add as keystore my certificate and made outgoing configuration, where are make timestmap and signature. In Signature, I configure it as binary security token, choose my keystore, alias and password. I have experimented with methods, but most closer result to correct one was this:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <u:Timestamp u:Id="TS-6EB3E416E924850AA51477473502423447">
        <u:Created>2016-10-26T09:18:22.423Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2016-10-26T09:23:22.423Z</u:Expires>
    </u:Timestamp>
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" u:Id="X509-6EB3E416E924850AA51477473502407442">...CCBGmgAwIBAgIKOeP(shortened)..." xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#id-6EB3E416E924850AA51477473502408445">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>ylZ7mgRanKsz3pYpbSXtE3FoVcc=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>...PwHLpHxINEYUGoCM+Tsz9ucg(shortened)...</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-6EB3E416E924850AA51477473502407443">
            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference u:Id="STR-6EB3E416E924850AA51477473502407444">
                <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-6EB3E416E924850AA51477473502407442" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</wsse:Security>
```

On this request, i have response with error message

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

One of differences what I see, is that in correct request there are two references with different URI, than in SoapUI request, but I can't figure out, how to simulate correct request in SoapUI. I would be glad to get some recommendation, maybe someone had the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

from default soapui only signs the soap-body element.
but you can add each other element from the "Parts:" configuration.

add the following (ID, Name, Namespace, Encode) in the Parts table:

First entry to sign timestamp content

- leave ID empty
- Timestamp
- http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd
- Element

Second entry to sign body content

- leave ID empty
- Body
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
- Element

and soapui will sign the timestamp **and** body element.

remark: the Timestamp needs to be added before the "Signature" in the list of WSS-Entries.